# render a component or render a video src embedded depending on screen size

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this code block and I will like to depending on the screen size either render the BackgroundImage component or a youtube video src

```
const HomePage = () => (
  <div>
    <BackgroundImageDiv />
  </div>
);
export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a hook like [useWindowSize](https://usehooks.com/useWindowSize/) and then conditionally render based on that -

```
function useWindowSize() {
  const isClient = typeof window === 'object';

  function getSize() {
    return {
      width: isClient ? window.innerWidth : undefined,
      height: isClient ? window.innerHeight : undefined
    };
  }

  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isClient) {
      return false;
    }

    function handleResize() {
      setWindowSize(getSize());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount

  return windowSize;
}
```

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const size = useWindowSize();

  return (
    <div>
      {size.width > 1000 ? <BackgroundImageDiv /> : <YouTube />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you wanna do is keep checking the width of the screen using the `window` object and save the value of the width in a state variable and then you can choose the screen size you want the component to change when it goes above or below that screen size and check that with state variable `width` and conditionally render based on that

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,Fragment } from "react";

    const HomePage = () => {
      const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
      const screenSize = width <= 500;
      useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => handleWindowSizeChange());
      }, []);

      const handleWindowSizeChange = () => {

          setWidth(window.innerWidth);

      };

      if (screenSize) {
        return <BackgroundImageDiv />;
      } else {
        return <Fragment>
        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube Link</a> 
     </Fragment>;
      }
    };

    export default HomePage;
```